# Which sentence is more common and idiomatic of the following?

Tags: past-tense

> 1. She got angry with what I said
> 2. She was angry with what I said

I think first one sounds more idiomatic
Because she was angry to me, sounds like her past state

And she got angry sounds more idiomatic. As it means she became angry with what I said

Comment: Both are fine. The former is more informal than the latter. The subtle difference is that "get" is more dynamic, describing the process of getting into that state.

Comment: Different nuance on user178049's comment.  "Got angry" refers to her immediate reaction upon hearing it, potentially the initiation of being angry.  "Was angry" refers to her subsequent mood over some period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Both the sentences sound ungrammatical.

You usually say you are angry with/at somebody and over/at something, not with something. So the sentences should be:

She got angry over/at what I said.

She was angry over/at what I said.

Both the sentences are different in meaning.

The former indicates that she became angry  or started to be in a state of being angry over what  I said, whereas the latter means that she was in a state of being angry over what I said.

Comment: +1 "Angry with" implies a situation and not a person or somebody.

Comment: "Both the sentences sound ungrammatical." Please explain, as this sounds like a subjective determination.

Comment: @SovereignSun/@user3169 , I said so because of the preposition "with". It should be over/at.